# Out of the box authentication solution for web apps?

Tags: authentication, web-applications

I'm a beginner when it comes to js/html/php. Whenever I've built a simple web app I'm faced with the arduous challenge of having to implement sign up and authentication. I have tried to find a service that handles this for me but surprisingly enough I can't find one.

Can someone recommend either:

1. a complete out of the box solution that handles the sign up and authentication for web apps

or...

2. a *good* tutorial on how to implement basic sign up/authentication with up-to-date technology?